# Double Integral of $(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}$ over $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq1, x+y\geq 1\}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the double integral of 
>   $$\int\int_{\mathcal{D}}(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}dxdy$$
>   where the domain $\mathcal{D} =\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq1, x+y\geq 1\}$.

I know that polar coordinates should be the easiest way to do the double integral but I am having trouble understanding how to convert the parameters to polar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: well i know the domain is a circle with a radius less than 1 and I know that if x+y is greater than 1 then the x and y intercepts are 1 and 1 but may extend somewhat into quadrants 2 and 4 I am not certain though

Comment: obviously x=r sin(theta) and y=cos(theta) so the inside part should yield 1/r^3 I think

Comment: oh wait and an r outside the parenthesis for the jacobian so 1/r^2?

Comment: but I am not sure if that is right or what the parameters to integrate by should be

Comment: An useful "trick" is integrate in a quarter of the circle and remove the area of the triangle in the quarter of that circle.

Comment: hey diego i solved it but i am also curious about your methodology i do not  understand how to solve it via your method if you want to elaborate i would appreciate it and find it interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**:$x = r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta \Rightarrow I = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{\cos\theta +\sin \theta}}^{1} (r^2)^{-3/2}rdrd\theta$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! I think so though give me a few minutes but out of curiosity and for future reference how did you get the parameter for r to be 1/cos(theta)+sin(theta) to 1

Comment: $x+y\geq 1 \to r\cos \theta+r\sin \theta \geq 1\to r(\cos \theta+\sin \theta) \geq 1\to r\geq \frac{1}{\cos \theta+\sin \theta}$, and $r^2 = x^2+y^2 \leq 1\to r^2 \leq 1\to r \leq 1$

Comment: wow why did I not do that. thank you!

Comment: (2pi/3)-(2/3) !?!

Comment: I just recalculuated that "the" upper limit of $\theta$ is $\pi/2$.

Comment: that makes sense I was just trying to think about that. thanks again. is there a way to calculate it similar to r or do you just have to picture the domain?

Comment: You draw a graph of the region and you can see it......

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map
$$
\Phi:(0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi)\to \mathbb{R}^2, \, \Phi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).
$$
Then the Jacobian $J_\Phi(r,\theta)$ is:
$$
J_\Phi(r,\theta)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{array}\right]
$$
and its determinant is
$$
\det(J_\Phi(r,\theta))=\left|\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{array}\right|=r\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta=r.
$$
Since
$$
\Phi^{-1}(D)=\left\{(r,\theta):\, (\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^{-1}\le r\le 1,\, 0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2 \right\},
$$
it follows that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_D(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac32}\,dx\,dy&=&\int_{\Phi^{-1}(D)}\left[\Phi_1^2(r,\theta)+\Phi_2^2(r,\theta)\right]^{-\frac32}\det(J_\Phi(r,\theta))\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=&\int_{\Phi^{-1}(D)}r^{-3}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{\Phi^{-1}(D)}r^{-2}\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=&\int_0^\frac\pi2\left[\int_{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^{-1}}^1r^{-2}\,dr\right]\,d\theta=\int_0^\frac\pi2\left[-r^{-1}\right]_{(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^{-1}}^1\,d\theta\\
&=&\int_0^\frac\pi2(\cos\theta+\sin\theta-1)\,d\theta=[\sin\theta-\cos\theta-\theta]_0^\frac\pi2\\
&=&1-\frac\pi2+1=2-\frac\pi2
\end{eqnarray}